# QProcess passing (shell) arguments

Tags: linux, qt, shell, qprocess

I'm trying to read the output of a shell script in Qt. However, passing an argument to the shell script doesn't work, as it is ignored completely. What am I doing wrong in the following excerpt?

```
QProcess *process = new QProcess;
process->start("sh", QStringList() << "-c" << "\"xdotool getactivewindow\"");
process->waitForFinished();
QString output = process->readAllStandardOutput();
target = output.toUInt();
```

I have looked at several other threads and tried solutions such as

```
process->start("sh", QStringList() << "-c" << "xdotool getactivewindow");
```

and

```
process->start("sh", QStringList() << "-c" << "xdotool" << "getactivewindow");
```

but none worked.

Comment: Does `process->start("xdotool", QStringList() << "getactivewindow");` work? What is the command if you execute it in the shell yourself?

Comment: In the shell I execute xdotool getactivewindow. And thx, `process->start("xdotool", QStringList() << "getactivewindow");` worked! I suspect the reason is that there is only one command without any space to escape. So the original question still remains kind of unsolved.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect that your second method should work.

I tested it with the following script (`test.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "First arg: $1"
echo "Second arg: $2"
```

And I called the script using `QProcess` in following ways:

```
QProcess *process = new QProcess;
process->start("./test.sh", QStringList() << "abc" << "xyz");
process->waitForFinished();
qDebug () << process->readAllStandardOutput();
// returns: "First arg: abc\nSecond arg: xyz\n" => OK

process->start("sh", QStringList() << "-c" << "./test.sh abc xyz");
process->waitForFinished();
qDebug () << process->readAllStandardOutput();
// returns: "First arg: abc\nSecond arg: xyz\n" => OK

process->start("sh", QStringList() << "-c" << "./test.sh" <<  "abc xyz");
process->waitForFinished();
qDebug () << process->readAllStandardOutput();
// returns: "First arg: \nSecond arg: \n" => WRONG
```

**Explanation**

- `process->start("sh", QStringList() << "-c" << "\"xdotool getactivewindow\"");`: it is not needed (nor allowed) to quote the arguments yourself. The [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#start) is not that clear, but it states:

> Note: No further splitting of the arguments is performed.

- `process->start("sh", QStringList() << "-c" << "xdotool getactivewindow");`: this should work
- `process->start("sh", QStringList() << "-c" << "xdotool" << "getactivewindow");`: `getactivewindow` is passed as an argument to `sh` instead of `xdotool`